# Terraform for cross account sns and sqs

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have an SQS in my account A that I want to subscribe to notifications to a SNS configured in another account B. I have no ownership of account B. I am using terraform for my project.

Going through the terraform documentation I found 
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/sns_topic_subscription.html

> NOTE: Setup of cross-account subscriptions from SNS topics to SQS queues requires Terraform to have access to BOTH accounts.
>   Is there a way to set this up without having access to account B?

Comment: Seems like this is still the case yeah?